# TAdvStringGrid is not aligning to full screen when form is maximized at run time

Tags: delphi

I put `TAdvStringGrid` (879 * 419) control on my delphi form (879 * 419) with properties `Align = alClient` & `Anchors = [akLeft, akTop, akRight, akBottom]` but when form is maximized at run time TAdvSTringGrid is not aligning to the max form size(1366 * 768) as shown in figure below which is showing white gap between `TAdvSTringGrid` table and max form size.

[image]

It seems like it is aligning `TAdvSTringGrid` component to full size but it is not stretching `TABLE & CELLS` to align with maximum size. How to make table align with full size ?

Comment: Another thing I noticed that when viewed as text code Anchors = [akLeft, akTop, akRight, akBottom] property is automatically disappearing from text code.

Comment: From a quick look in [`the documentation`](http://www.tmssoftware.com/ACGDOC.HTM) I don't think you can configure a single column for autosizing to fit the grid width. I'd do it manually in `OnResize` event (if there's any).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked out finally with the `ColumnSize Stretch` property of TAdvStringGrid by setting out `ColumnSize.Stretch = True` which helped me align TAdvSTringGrid table to the full screen..